# TortoiseHg: Is there any way to update icons from a batch file?

Tags: tortoisehg

TortoiseHg: Is there any way to update icons from a batch file?

I find I'm all the time updating icons from the TortoiseHg menu, and I would like to trigger the Icons update from batch file, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Sort of. You need to open a specific named pipe and then send a command. As far as I know you're going to have to write a (admittedly very small) script or app to do that, but then that script can be wrapped in a batch file.

The pipe name is:
TortoiseHgRpcServer-bc0c27107423-[username]
(for the computer I'm writing this on it's TortoiseHgRpcServer-bc0c27107423-nholley)

The command is:
update|[path-to-update]
(so my test uses update|c:\projects\scripts)

A short C# command-line app to do this is

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;

namespace NamedPipeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var username = Environment.UserName;
            using (var pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream("TortoiseHgRpcServer-bc0c27107423-" + username))
            {
                try
                {
                    pipe.Connect(1000);

                    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(pipe))
                    {
                        sw.Write("update|" + args[0]);
                    }
                }
                catch (TimeoutException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Named pipe could not be found. Please restart TortoiseHgOverlayServer");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should at least get you started. It's worth noting that the explorer shell seems to call remove|[path] followed up update|[path] but I can't tell that the remove step is actually necessary, and when I tried doing that in the above program I would get a "Pipe is broken" exception after the second command, though the command actually made it through to the overlay server. Someone who knows more about named pipes could probably fix that easily.

If you want to dig into it more take a look at https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/src/bcf0eaf6db6a/TortoiseHgOverlayServer.py

Whee, that was fun!

edit: Use the correct keywords for the language and added a bit more error checking.

Comment: I changed the first [import] statements for using. That made it to compile, however it stays at black screen indefinitely

Comment: For some reason TortoiseHgOverlayServer lost its handle on the named pipe. A simple timeout check and try-catch resolves that. You can of course expand it to automatically restart that exe, but that's beyond the scope of this question.